# Passing information from popup form back to the original form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, properties

This question is similar to questions that have been asked before. The solutions in the other questions have not worked for me.

I have a form that has a dropdown list. One of the choices opens up a new form with two more dropdown lists. I need to pass the information from the form that popped up back to the original form without making a new instance of it. The information from the popup will make calculations and add new items to the dropdown list in the original form.

I've tried using properties but I was only retrieving default values since a new instance was made. What is the correct method for passing information in this manner?

Comment: What do you mean that you were "retrieving default values" by using properties? Could you post some actual code?